# Type assertion to interfaces, what happens internally

Tags: go, methods, interface, type-assertion

I am curious about what happens internally when Go performs type assertion with another interface being its destination. Just for sake of example, consider this example from [Dave Cheney's blog](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully):

```
type temporary interface {
    Temporary() bool
}

// IsTemporary returns true if err is temporary.
func IsTemporary(err error) bool {
        te, ok := err.(temporary)
        return ok && te.Temporary()
}
```

I would expect quite a lot of runtime overhead to happen here, since it has to inspect the type of `err` and find whether it has all the methods in place. Is that so, or is there some smart magic happening underneath?

Comment: Well, that are pure implementation details and not every compiler must, can, will, or will do in the future or did in the past the same. If curious about a certain compiler at a certain time: Check the source.

Comment: @Volker thank you for your informative answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expectations you described are valid and hold. The runtime has to check if the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the dynamic type is a superset of the interface type you want to assert to.

But fear not. Implementation to do this is heavily optimized (this is your "smart magic").

For a start, function types are internally described by a struct, where the method signature (parameter and result types) are represented by a single integer value called the *signature id*. If 2 functions have the same signature, they have the same signature id. So to compare 2 functions (to tell if 2 methods are the same) the runtime only has to compare the names (string comparison) and signature ids (integer comparison).

Next, whether a dynamic type `T` implements an interface `I` is only checked / calculated **once**, and the result is cached. So even though there is some work involved in this check, it will not be executed multiple times, just once, and whenever the same type check is needed (the same type assertion), the cached result will be looked up and used.

**So ultimately what a type assertion to interface type boils down to is: (1) calculate a hash value (some bitwise operations), (2) look up a value from a map and (3) construct the result interface value.**

For an introduction about interface representation, read [Russ Cox: Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

Here is an article which holds all the details about the above: [**How interfaces work in Go**](https://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-interface-implementation)

For example the relevant part to describe a function is:

```
type _func struct {
    name      string  
    methodSig uint // two methods with the same signature have
                   // the same signature id. Receiver parameter
                   // doesn't contribute to this signature.
    funcSig   uint // receiver parameter accounts to this signature.

    // other information ...
}
```

**Type Assert To Interface Types:**

Here is the internal function to assert an interface value to an interface type:

```
// To call this function, compilers must assure 
// 1. itype is an interface type.
// 2. outI is nil or stores the address of a value of itype.
// 3. outOk is nil or stores the address of a bool value.
func assertI2I (ivalue _interface, itype *_type,
        outI *_interface, outOk *bool) {
    // dynamic value is untype nil.
    if ivalue.dynamicTypeInfo == nil {
        // if ok is not present, panic.
        if outOk == nil {
            panic("interface is nil, not " + itype.name)
        }

        *outOk = false
        if outI == nil {
            *outI = _interface {
                dynamicValue:    nil,
                dynamicTypeInfo: nil,
            }
        }

        return
    }

    // check whether or not the dynamic type implements itype
    var impl = getImpl(itype, ivalue.dynamicTypeInfo.dtype)

    // assersion fails.
    if impl == nil {
        // if ok is not present, panic.
        if outOk == nil {
            panic("interface is " +
                ivalue.dynamicTypeInfo.dtype.name +
                ", not " + itype.name)
        }

        // return (zero value, false)
        *outOk = false
        if outI != nil {
            *outI = _interface {
                dynamicValue:    nil,
                dynamicTypeInfo: nil,
            }
        }

        return
    }

    // assersion succeeds.

    if outI == nil {
        *outOk = true
    }
    if outI != nil {
        *outI = _interface {
            dynamicValue:    ivalue.dynamicValue,
            dynamicTypeInfo: impl,
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the function to get an `_implementation` value from an interface type and a non-interface type:**

```
// global table
var cachedImpls = map[uint64]*_implementation{}

// itype must be an interface type and
// dtype must be a non-interface type.
// Return nil if dtype doesn't implement itype.
// Must not return nil if dtype implements itype.
func getImpl (itype *_type, dtype *_type) *_implementation {
    var key = uint64(itype.id) << 32 | uint64(dtype.id)
    var impl = cachedImpls[key]
    if impl == nil {
        // for each (dtype, itype) pair, the implementation
        // method table is only calculated most once at
        // run time. The calculation result will be cached.

        var numMethods = len(itype.methods)
        var methods = make([]*_func, numMethods)

        // find every implemented methods.
        // The methods of itype and dtype are both sorted
        // by methodSig and name.
        var n = 0
        var i = 0
        for _, im := range itype.methods {
            for i < len(dtype.methods) {
                tm := dtype.methods[i]
                i++

                // Here, for simplicity, assume
                // all methods are exported.

                if tm.methodSig < im.methodSig {
                    continue
                }
                if tm.methodSig > im.methodSig {
                    // im method is not implemented
                    return nil
                }
                if tm.name < im.name {
                    continue
                }
                if tm.name > im.name {
                    // im method is not implemented
                    return nil
                }

                methods[n] = tm
                n++
                break
            }
        }

        // dtype doesn't implement all methods of itype
        if n < numMethods {
            return nil
        }

        // dtype implements itype.
        // create and cache the implementation.
        impl = &_implementation{
            dtype: dtype, 
            itype: itype, 
            methods: methods,
        }
        cachedImpls[key] = impl
    }

    return impl
}
```

Comment: An addendum: while it is true that type assertions are quite cheap, you shouldn't start throwing around type assertions everywhere and passing all values using the empty interface (if you wanted to do that - just use python! :P). Use type assertions on proper interfaces in cases like OP's example (getting more information out of an error), and try to use the empty interface as little as possible and only when absolutely necessary [(as Rob Pike said, "`interface{}` means nothing").](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=7m36s)

Comment: I'd also recommend reading [this article](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces). The today's Go differs from that a little bit—`uintptr`-sized values no more get embedded directly into interface values—but the rest still applies, and the idea of how the interfaces are implemeneted is explained very well IMO.

Comment: @kostix Yes, that was the link I first wanted to include, but the other holds direct answer to how type assertions work, so I went with that and forgot about this one in the process of making the answer.